# AppBarLayout + TabLayout + CollapsingToolbarLayout + SwipeToRefresh

Tags: android, android-toolbar, swiperefreshlayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I met a lot of issues related with my problem but nobody I found wanted the behaviour I'm looking for.

I want a view pager with tabs and app bar, when the contained fragments are scrollable and are scrolled (toward bottom), I want the app bar to disapear but leave the tabs, when scrolled toward top, to re-apear. some of these fragments contain a SwipeToRefresh Layout (sometimes it causes problems).
I tried a lot of configurations that always leave something wrong.

for now I don't have the collapsing effect (it's always hidden)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainPagerActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar_layout"
        tools:context=".MainPagerActivity"

        />

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />
```

and one of my fragment (the scrolling one) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.m360learning.app.fragment.MainPagerNewsFeed">


    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.pnikosis.materialishprogress.ProgressWheel
                android:id="@+id/progress_wheel"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                wheel:matProg_barColor="#5588FF"
                wheel:matProg_progressIndeterminate="true" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I don't know exactly what I've done but from the time I started write this question the refreshLayout prevent my List from going up (it refreshes instead)..

Thanks

------Correction !

thanks to Sir Ellie Zou, it now works with this xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainPagerActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">




            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainPagerActivity"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

        />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and the fragment layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.m360learning.app.fragment.MainPagerNewsFeed">


    <com.pnikosis.materialishprogress.ProgressWheel
        android:id="@+id/progress_wheel"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        wheel:matProg_barColor="#5588FF"
        wheel:matProg_progressIndeterminate="true" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />


    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't want parallax effect, you don't need to use `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Most important configuration:

In Toolbar, set `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`.

In ViewPager, set `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`.

And layout should look like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Move `ProgressWheel` out of your `SwipeRefreshLayout` to fix your problem that SwipeRefreshLayout can't refresh.

Comment: Oups sorry, I didn't notice but the swipeToRefresh is stille broken, any idea ?

Comment: try to move `ProgressWheel` out of  `SwipeRefreshLayout`

Comment: Hello again, I'm trying now to do quite the same thing, but with a collapsing image on top of it. How should I go ?

Comment: @RenaudFavier use `CollapsingToolbarLayout `

Comment: I have a bug with my title. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184273/collapsingtoolbarlayout-tablayout-strange-toolbar-title-margin

Comment: The tip with the ViewPager made it. THANKS!