# CollapsingToolbarLayout + TabLayout, strange toolbar title margin

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a srange toolbar title behaviour that I doubt to be valid.

collapsed :

[image: collapsed toolbar]

extended :

[image: extended toolbar]

The strangest part is that the

> app:titleMarginTop

does not have any effect on the title placement.

Here is my Xml  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.m360learning.app.activity.UserDetailsActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="@drawable/background_navigation_drawer"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside" />

            </RelativeLayout>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"

                 />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

---Edit : 
If I set the toolbar size to "actionbarsize"

[image]

And it doesn't change the expanded behaviour.

------------ FINAL EDIT -- CORRECTION

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/background_navigation_drawer"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:paddingEnd="30dp"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:paddingStart="30dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                ......


            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleMarginTop="15dp" />



        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#99FFFFFF"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Why dont you set Toolbar height as `?attr/actionBarSize` ?

Comment: if I do so when the toolbar collapses the tabBar displays over it instead of below

Comment: Use tabs inside of collapsingToolbar and toolbar should be actionbarsize instead

Comment: Hum my tab is already inside collapsingToolbar.

The toolbar size seems to be taken as the size of the collapsed toolbar. That's why I force it to be approx twice the actionbarsize

Comment: I'll add a screenshot of what happend if I do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your TabLayout should be outside your CollapsingToolbarLayout while still inside your AppBarLayout:

```
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

A tab section is part of the app bar, but *not* part of the tool bar.

Comment: Nice ! I was sure that I tried this.. I update my xml

Comment: would you by any chance know how to reduce the margin below the title when the toolbar is expanded ?

Comment: Not offhand. There could be a style for the TextView in the Toolbar, but I couldn't find it in Theme.AppCompat.  The only other thing I could suggest is to call `setSupportActionBar()` on the toolbar, then call `setCustomView()` on the action bar to set up a TextView where you can control the margins and vertical alignment.  I recommend that you post another question and left the SO community take a swing at it.

Comment: Hum, thanks I'll do that, I'll first explore a little bit more by myself thought

Answer (score 5):

[@kris larson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34187655/1973391) answer is ok but unfortunatelly doesn't work if we want transparent parallaxed `TabLayout` background. To make it works you need to do as follows:

- add `expandedTitleMarginBottom` to `CollapsingToolbarLayout`
- set `layout_height` to `TabLayout` as constant value
- add `layout_marginBottom` to `Toolbar` with same value as `TabLayout` height

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="56dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <YourMagicViewWithBackgroundImageTextAndOtherStuff
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```