# How to set Collapsing ToolBar height

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using Collapse ToolBar to make the layout as follow.But the ToolBar is not set properly. Now I am setting ToolBar Height as 100dp. If I reduce it, the ViewPager where the Tabs are set is overlapped on the ToolBar.

[image]

This is my xml.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/slide_image"
                    android:background="@drawable/slide_transparent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dashboard_txt_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:text="Salad"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dashboard_txt_des"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:text="@string/welcome_des"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />


                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_layout"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:titleMarginTop="15dp"
                    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />


                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white" />


            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


            <!--<include layout="@layout/activity_collapse_toolbar" />-->
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <!--<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />-->
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
                    android:foreground="@drawable/slide_transparent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/slide_image"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dashboard_txt_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:text="Salad"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dashboard_txt_des"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/dashboard_txt_title"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:text="@string/welcome_des"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />


                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/dashboard_txt_des"
                    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_layout"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:titleMarginTop="15dp"
                    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />


                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white" />


            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


            <!--<include layout="@layout/activity_collapse_toolbar" />-->
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_below="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <!--<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />-->
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Expect Result:[image]

Comment: remove   `android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"` from your xml file and test it.

Comment: Sorry..Still it is same as before.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe it's an old answer but there are 2 simple solutions:

## 1. `Toolbar` with `layout_marginBottom`

If you need to have a transparent (or semi transparent) `TabLayout` then you can do something like this:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <YourMagicViewWithBackgroundImageTextAndOtherStuff
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
            android:background="@color/semiTransparentHeaderBg"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/semiTransparentHeaderBg" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

---

## 2. `TabLayout` outside `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

If you don't need to have a transparent `TabLayout` then just put them outside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` as [kris larson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34187655/1973391) or [winter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35202420/1973391) suggests. `AppBarLayout` extend from `LinearLayout` so everything should works flawlessly.

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <YourMagicViewWithBackgroundImageTextAndOtherStuff
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/semiTransparentHeaderBg"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your CollapsingToolbarLayout each ImageView,TextView set

**android:layout_below="@+id/yourid "**

set each widget one by one below of other widget based on your designview order.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"

                android:background="@drawable/toolbar_layout"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleMarginTop="15dp"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                android:foreground="@drawable/slide_transparent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/slide_image"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dashboard_txt_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                android:text="Salad"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dashboard_txt_des"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/header"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/dashboard_txt_title"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                android:text="@string/welcome_des"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15dp" />





            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_below="@+id/dashboard_txt_des"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


        <!--<include layout="@layout/activity_collapse_toolbar" />-->
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<!--<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />-->
```

Comment: I attached an expect screenshot of layout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104016/discussion-between-sasikumar-and-parama-sudha).

Answer (score 0):

The below code works fine and  look like code very close look that you required

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="slidenerd.vivz.navigationviewdemo.FourthActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="192dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/rsz_bg_cover"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabTextColor="#EEE" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="mini" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Screen shots will be like

[image]

[image]

Also refer this link for more  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqvwA58b9l8&index=59&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD

Hope this helps you

Comment: Let me know tour result

Comment: By using this code toolbar is set that I expected.But when I scroll up,ToolBar is hidden by the Tabs.

Comment: But,I need to get the view of  second attached image. Anyhow Thank you for your answer.

Comment: When it scroll up,ViewPager Tab should be below the ToolBar.This is what I am trying to get.

Comment: It s too didnt work properly.ToolBar is set.But when I tried to move it up,Tab ViewPager didnt scroll up.

Comment: The youtube link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Change your xml file as below

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
           />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>





    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I too had the same issue and i solved it by this way.