# How do I make a TabLayout place below Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, android-tablayout

I got something when I was trying to add TabLayout below the Toolbar. I've tried a tab like suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752493/appbarlayout-tablayout-collapsingtoolbarlayout-swipetorefresh) by adding `<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout />`, but it positioned at the top of the Toolbar. And when I do anything like [this blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html), it's still not working.

This's my code. I created it from `scrolling activity` and I just made the change by adding `tablayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.myquestionth.myquestionth10.activity.Profile4Activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_profile4" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I just want Tablayout placing like this:
[image]

And this when the Toolbar is scrolled away:
[image]

Please help and suggest.

Answer (score 5):

This is an example from one of my projects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_48dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In my project I was using `viewpager` instead of `TabLayout`.

Comment: I've tried your code but no Tab layout appears on the screen. I have no idea right now. It shouldn't be this. I've added tab items in java code as well.

Comment: i updated my answer, i inserted a `viewpager ` to the `TabLayout `

Answer (score 0):

Change the height attributes of tab layout. Like this

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar LeftDrawer TabLayout ListView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--The mait Context-->
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView1" />
    <!--The left Navigator Drawer-->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#818181"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:background="#E3F2FD" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```